# Storing extracted content of the zip file in different directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is working fine but my question is, how do I extract the zip file's content into a different directory?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'zip/zip'

Zip::ZipFile.open("j.zip") do |zipfile|
    zipfile.each do |file|
    file.extract
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Change the Working Directory

There may be other ways to address this issue, but one of the most obvious is to change the current working directory with [Dir#chdir](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-chdir). For example, to extract your files into `/tmp`:

```
old_pwd = Dir.pwd
Dir.chdir '/tmp'
# run your commands here
```

Comment: Or pass a block to `Dir.chdir`, and execute your commands inside that block. When the block exits, Ruby will do a "popdir" automatically.

Comment: Actually my j.zip file is in the current working directory., if i use your code .. it raises the error "file not found"

Comment: @JabaJawahar You can pass an absolute path to #open, or construct a path to it using `old_pwd` or similar.